# Palindrome number code not working for fringe cases

Tags: c++, algorithm

I've been doing some leetcode questions but I hitched at this one: `Given an integer x, return true if x is palindrome integer.`

It works for almost all cases, except for numbers like 12321 or 88888

Why doesn't it work

```
class Solution {
    public:
        bool isPalindrome(int x) {
            if(x < 0 || (x % 10 == 0 && x != 0))
                return false;
            
            int z = 0, p = 1; 
            while (x > z)
            {
                z = z * p + x % 10;
                x = x / 10;
                p = p * 10;
            }
            return x == z || x == z / 10;
    }
};
```

Comment: It would be simpler to convert the number to a string and then check if the string is a palindrome.

Comment: I thought of doing that, but the constraint was to not use strings

Comment: This doesn't really address the question, but unless there's a definition of "palindrome integer" somewhere, this problem can't be solved. The code here assumes that 'palindrome integer" means "the result of converting the integer to text **in base 10** is a palindrome". Base 10 isn't an unreasonable assumption, but it's not part of the problem statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
                z = z * p + x % 10;
```

is wrong. `z` should be shifted by one digit. The shift size shouldn't be changed in the loop. Using the line, the value will be `x = 12, z = 1203` after the loop for the input `12321`. You see the extra `0` is inserted. It is because you used the wrong shift size.

The line should be

```
                z = z * 10 + x % 10;
```